# I cannot get past the To Curse the Darkness quest

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

After I visited the site, I cannot find where there supposed to be handholds before reaching the flat rock, then to where there is a Bonfire for saving, waiting for me on the top. I learned this through youtube.

How can I get past this main quest?

Comment: Are you saying to can't find the handholds? Have to actually been given this quest yet? The handholds aren't there until you get the quest.

Comment: Yes correct. Even though I finished all of the side quest and errands still I cannot find the hand holds. now my characters level is already 41. i already have the ques(go to the location that sylens indicated). after arriving on the yellow spot still it says-go to the location that sylens indicated. what did i did wrong???

Comment: If possible, can you add a screenshot of where you expect the handholds to be, based on either other guides or the objective marker?

Comment: The handholds are right on the quest marker labelled 'Climb the Escarpment'. Aloy should say 'there are the handholds'. This is just after a conversation with Sylens where Aloy complains that she 'does all the dangerous stuff'.

Comment: I know where the handholds will be. it just beside the stream, however, its not shown. even after arriving on the spot, quest marker does not change, and Aloy does not say anything. I tried climbing using Charger as my leverage, but after arriving on top there is no BONFIRE to save. is this a glitch in the game??

Comment: To reduce the likelihood that this is the result of a glitch, have you tried loading from a slightly older save to see if you find anything different?

Comment: Unfortunately, i dont have any old saved file. everything is Automatically saved outright. shocks....

Answer (score 2):

**The handholds are slightly past where the campfire is, near the crevasse with the creek coming out through it.**

Video:

You can also get up there by fast traveling to the campfire. If you got close enough to discover the campfire, you can fast travel to it without having saved at it previously. I've done this a few times with similar campfires that were at the top of a climb.